# SQLite Database not updating on updating App from Play Store even after incrementing the database version

Tags: android, sqlite

I am stuck with a frustrating situation. I have an SQlite database class as below:

```
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ABC/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "ABCdb.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private static int DATABASE_VERSION=2;

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
        // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
        // writable database, but only if the version number has been increased

        this.getWritableDatabase();
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            // throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return myDataBase;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    System.out.println("NewVersion : "+newVersion+", OldVersion : "+oldVersion);
    if(newVersion>oldVersion){
        myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
// database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd
// be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.
```

}

The uploaded app on play store has DATABASE_VERSION set to 1.I have added some new tables in the DB.I increment the DATABASE_VERSION to 2. But when i run the app with debug keystore then onUpgrade() method is called and DB is upgrading but when i sign the App and then update the installed App it is not upgrading the database. I don't know whether i am missing something. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only be able to upgrade the debug version of your app with another debug version of your app.  The same is true of release versions.  The release version can only be upgraded with another release version.  Put another way - it is only an upgrade if you replace the app with an app that has been signed with the same key.

Thus, from what you describe (failure to upgrade DB when using the release version), it sounds as if you have replaced the debug version with the release version.  Android will recognize this scenario as the same app, however it will first un-install the initial version (debug) and then replace it with the new version (release).  Thus, although it may appear to the user as an upgrade, this is actually an un-install/install scenario.

As far as I know, that is the only way to explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I have used the below scenario to test this-

Comment: Firstly i signed my app with release key store. Then i incremented the DB version and again signed with release keystore and installed it.This time installation wizard told that if need to update. I did an update and the DB was upgraded. But when i uploaded my app after incrementing the DB version and then updating it from Play Store . This time the DB is not upgrading. I know this is weird but didn't know whats happening.